# How do I use Firebase Simple Login with email & password

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Firebase Simple login provides an [email/password](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-email-password.html) option, how do I use it? Starting from from creating a user, storing data for that user, to logging them in and out.

Comment: http://engineering.letsnurture.com/firebase-basic-authentication/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are three distinct steps to be performed (let's assume you have jQuery):

**1. Set up your callback**

```js
var ref = new Firebase("https://demo.firebaseio-demo.com");
var authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(ref, function(error, user) {
  if (error) {
    alert(error);
    return;
  }
  if (user) {
    // User is already logged in.
    doLogin(user);
  } else {
    // User is logged out.
    showLoginBox();
  }
});
```

**2. User registration**

```js
function showLoginBox() {
  ...
  // Do whatever DOM operations you need to show the login/registration box.
  $("#registerButton").on("click", function() {
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    authClient.createUser(email, password, function(error,  user) {
      if (!error) {
        doLogin(user);
      } else {
        alert(error);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

**3. User login**

```js
function showLoginBox() {
  ...
  // Do whatever DOM operations you need to show the login/registration box.
  $("#loginButton").on("click", function() {
    authClient.login("password", {
      email: $("#email").val(),
      password: $("#password").val(),
      rememberMe: $("#rememberCheckbox").val()
    });
  });
}
```

When the login completes successfully, the call you registered in step 1 will be called with the correct user object, at which point we call `doLogin(user)` which is a method you will have to implement.

The structure of the user data is very simple. It is an object containing the following properties:

`email`: Email address of the user
`id`: Unique numeric (auto-incrementing) ID for the user

FirebaseAuthClient will automatically authenticate your firebsae for you, not further action is required. You can now use something like the following in your security rules:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$userid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $userid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $userid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This means, if my User ID is 42, only I can write or read at `example.firebaseio-demo.com/users/42` - when I am logged in - and no-one else.

Note that Simple Login does not store any additional information about the user other than their ID and email. If you want to store additional data about the user, you must do so yourself (probably in the success callback for `createUser`). You can store this data as you normally would store any data in Firebase - just be careful about who can read or write to this data!

Comment: Is there anyway we can do email verification to prevent user simple use fake email ?

Comment: Email verification is coming soon, watch the Firebase mailing list for an announcement!

Comment: @Anant It could be great if  you provide seed app in github to work with  AngularJs + Firebase which includes Firebase auth using Github and Facbook with latest version of both Angular and Firebase?

Comment: @Anant Is `FirebaseAuthClient` some private custom object or is it provided by Firebase? Since as far as I understand, then according to Firebase spec. `Firebase` object should be enought.

Answer (score 4):

Just incase someone is reached to this thread and looking for some example application using the firebase authentication. Here are two examples

```
var rootRef = new Firebase('https://docs-sandbox.firebaseio.com/web/uauth');
......
.....
....
```

http://jsfiddle.net/firebase/a221m6pb/embedded/result,js/

http://www.42id.com/articles/firebase-authentication-and-angular-js/