# firebase simple authentication authClient is null?

Tags: authentication, firebase

Below is the sample code I am playing around with:

```
var myRootRef = new Firebase('https://url.firebaseIO.com/');

var authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(myRootRef, function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
        // an error occurred while attempting login
        console.log(error);
    } else if (user) {
        // user authenticated with Firebase
        console.log('User ID: ' + user.id + ', Provider: ' + user.provider);
    } else {
        // user is logged out

        console.log('logged out!');
        login();
    }
});


function login(){
    var email = "something@gmail.com";
    var password = "123";

    authClient.login('password', {
        email: email,
        password: password,
        rememberMe: true
    });
}
```

The error I get back is : Cannot call method 'login' of undefined

authClient seems to be always null? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Engineer at Firebase] @Kato is correct, and this is because the first callback you're getting (for the logged-out state) is being invoked synchronously. I'm going to change this behavior so that is invoked asynchronously, which should address the problem you ran into, though all of the other solutions suggested here are correct too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here **authClient** seems good. I think problem with scope of the login() function.Try this

```
    var myRootRef = new Firebase('https://url.firebaseIO.com/');
    var authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(myRootRef, function(error, user) {
        if (error) {
            // an error occurred while attempting login
            console.log(error);
        } else if (user) {
            // user authenticated with Firebase
            console.log('User ID: ' + user.id + ', Provider: ' + user.provider);
        } else {
            // user is logged out

            console.log('logged out!');

        var email = "something@gmail.com";
        var password = "123";

        this.login('password', {
            email: email,
            password: password,
            rememberMe: true
        });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why do I need to scope it like that? I've seen a few other authentication answers in here that dont scope it like that? They call on a function that access the auth client and calls the login function?

Comment: Like this example, it shows the scoping like how I have done it and yet it seems to work for other people? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167981/how-do-i-use-firebase-simple-login-with-email-password?rq=1

Comment: @TriFu to build on my answer below, the reason the example you've listed here works is because `authClient.login` is not invoked until a button is clicked, allowing time for the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

When you initially call `new FirebaseAuthClient`, it's going to invoke the callback with the current login state (The user could already be logged in, for instance, when this is invoked). This callback occurs before `new FirebaseAuthClient` returns, which means that `authClient` has not been assigned yet.

You do not need to move the your `authClient.login` inside the callback, although this works fine. You just need to be aware of the fact that the first time this callback is issued might be before the assignment.

You could, for instance, use a `setTimeout` around your call to ensure the variable is set first:

```
var authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(myRootRef, function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
        // an error occurred while attempting login
        console.log(error);
    } else if (user) {
        // user authenticated with Firebase
        console.log('User ID: ' + user.id + ', Provider: ' + user.provider);
    } else {
        // user is logged out
        console.log('not logged in yet or logged out again!');
        setTimeout(login, 1);
    }
});
```