# email/password authentication for firebase SERVER_ERROR

Tags: javascript, email, authentication, passwords, firebase

I'm trying to use Firebase's simple login and attempting to follow the general methods laid out in [How do I use Firebase Simple Login with email & password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167981/how-do-i-use-firebase-simple-login-with-email-password).

Everytime I try to create a new user (or sign in), however, I get a

> SERVER_ERROR: The connection to wss://s-xxxxxxxx was interrupted while the page was loading.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Also, it works on Firefox when I hardcode values (i.e. take createUser outside of the register submit handler), but not on Chrome.

`login.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-simple-login.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="login_or_register">
        </div>
        <button id="logout">Logout</button>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='loginScript.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`loginScript.js`

```
function showLoginRegister(auth){

                    $register_form = $('<form id="register">'+
                      '<input type="text" name="register-email" id="register-email" value="email@example.com">'+
                    '<input type="password" name="register-password" id="register-password" value="password">'+
                    '<input type="submit" value="Create an account!"/>'+'</form>')

                    $login_form = $('<form id="login">'+'<input type="text" name="login-email" id="login-email" value="email@example.com">'+
                    '<input type="password" name="login-password" id="login-password" value="password">'+
                    '<input type="checkbox" name="rememberCheckbox" id="rememberCheckbox" checked>'+
                    '<input type="submit" value="Sign in"/>'+'</form>')
                    $('#login_or_register').append($register_form,$login_form);

                    $("#register").submit(function() {
                        var email = $("#register-email").val();
                    var password = $("#register-password").val();
                    auth.createUser(email, password, function(error, user) {
                            if (!error) {
                                  auth.login("password", {
                                  email: email,
                                    password: password,
                                    rememberMe: false
                                });
                            }
                            else{
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    $("#login").submit(function() {
                        var email = $("#login-email").val();
                    var password = $("#login-password").val();
                    var checkbox = $("#rememberCheckbox").val();
                      auth.login("password", {
                            email: email,
                            password: password,
                            rememberMe: checkbox
                        });
                    });  
                };


                var ref = new Firebase('https://xxx.firebaseio.com/');
                var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(ref, function(error, user) {
                    if (error){
                        console.log(error);
                      return;
                  }
                  if (user) {
                    // user authenticated with Firebase
                        $("#logout").click(function(){
                            auth.logout();
                       })
                  } 
                  else {
                    showLoginRegister(this);
                      // user is logged out
                  }
                });
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're seeing is that the network request for the login methods are failing since you're navigating away from the current page before they can complete. The form is actually being submitted, and the page is redirecting / refreshing as a result.

In order to prevent this behavior, update your code to include a `return false;` at the bottom of each of the `$(element).submit()` methods, which will prevent the form from submitting and the authentication requests will complete.

```
$("#el").submit(function() {
  // Do stuff here ...
  return false;
});
```