# Firebase: Is it secure enough?

Tags: angularjs, security, firebase, sails.js

I'm working on a project which deals with **real time data** as well as **online transactions**. Previously i was thinking to build it one Node.js with Sails framework. But yesterday i come across a service called **FireBase** and I was like WOW, that's exactly what i was looking for. After reading couple of blog posts about it, I'm kinda confused.

Is it secure enough to **handle payment data** provided by users. I'll be using a third party payment gateway so no need to worry about credit card details.  All the payment processing will be done on some incredibly secure server. But still is it good enough to guard data from hackers. I don't want someone to peak into my database. I know this question seems quite confusing. I just want to make my application as secure as possible.

Comment: Do you want to protect the [confidentiality](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2012/08/confidentiality-integrity-availability-the-three-components-of-the-cia-triad/) of data that a user enters into a payment form, and you're wondering how FireBase helps you?

Comment: Does FireBase generate the payment form or do you?

Comment: Does your app route payment details through a confirmation page before sending the details to the payment gateway?

Comment: What does real-time data have to do with payment processing?

Comment: Can you link to the blog posts that confused you?

Comment: Is leakage via your DB your only concern, or are you concerned about leakage of data as HTTP requests/responses fly back and forth?

Comment: I won't be creating the payment form. But yes the payment gateway will redirect back to my site with confirmation. What if the user spoofs the request and pretends to be the gateway? And i want to secure user data (privacy concerns) and payment processing is just a part of it there will be lot of dynamic content on the site. So the question is... Is firebase good enough to safeguard my user's data like email password etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **Firebase is Secure**. [This answe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23984895/3366109)r could help you. Moreover, I recommend you to read [where Firebase fit in your app](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-03-25-where-does-firebase-fit.html) before develop something; which might be really helpful if you want to create an awesome solution.