# Will Firebase be a safe baas option for an eCommerce flutter app in production?

Tags: firebase, flutter, security, sdk, razorpay

If I am integrating **Firebase** and **flutter** using the *SDK integrations* and not using any server side functions, what would be the possible ways the attackers could attack my app even if I secure the app with **Firebase Authentication** and use *strict database rules*. Iam planning on using **RazorPay** as the payment gateway which is also *SDK integrated* with the flutter app.

Basically what I am trying to ask is : If all of my **Firebase Authentication**, **Firebase Database** crud operations and **RazorPay** payment gateway is integrated into the client-side flutter app, is it going to be secure and if not what are the main negatives that an attacker can utilise?

And if there are lots of negatives and 0 positives why are they allowing the *SDK integration* option in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is a very secure BaaS as it gives you many options to secure your data. It's only insecure if the developer didn't secure it properly (incorrect/insufficient security rules, not protecting API keys, etc). I recommend their [security checklist](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/security-checklist) before you push to production to ensure your application is following Firebase guidelines.

Make sure to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981346/is-firebase-really-secure) other answer for more detail.